# C# regular expression for the string format. Examples: "400-900", "499-999,0-99"

Tags: c#, regex

The regular expression: "^\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}$" works for onetime pattern i.e. "400-900" but the regular expression with ? is not working for the repetition i.e. "^\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}$?" is not identifying the string "499-999,0-99".

Any suggestions, what the regular expression be?

Comment: The first answer on the "already answered" page will guide you in the right direction ...

Answer (score 1):

Change your pattern like below to match also the strings which has repetation.

```
@"^\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})?$"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nC9iV4/2)

Comment: the repetition would only be at the max once. i.e. "499-999,0-99" is not it could go up to and not more than that. Does that make any difference in using the above?

Comment: replace `*` with `?` , this turn the second non-capturing group as optional one.